# EWW: very slow opening of certain pages

Tags: emacs, eww

I'm using EWW Emacs browser for opening various remote pages(mostly documentation) which is very handy most of the time.

I'm still trying to understand why certain pages take 4-5-6+ seconds to be rendered in eww(which take <1s in Chrome, for comparison).

For my tasks, I only care about the loaded content - images and fancy styles are not needed.

Is there any simple way to speed it up?
Like setting readable mode/disabling images before calling eww? If that's possible at all.

---

***Update from a few weeks later***

I made a few experiments and from what I found the biggest contributing factor in my case is when a page has lots of third-party fonts.
I wasn't able to find a way to disable font fetching in [eww source code](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/net/eww.el) so probably true "text based" browser like `w3m` was a better solution in the first place.

Any clarification comments and answers are still very welcome.

Comment: Have you tried [profiling](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Profiling.html#Profiling) the code?

Comment: Can you try changing the fontset used and see if it makes a difference?

Comment: @Sandeep looks like fonts is the biggest slowdown reason but I wasn't able to prevent them from being loaded in eww

Comment: i am not getting any slowdown in eww. In my case it was mostly other emacs utils (linnum-column-mode, helm-autocomplete) etc. that were getting called during the rendering. Could you share a webpage and some rendering timings?